# Skip not found images on google open images v7

Tags: computer-vision, google-image-search

I want to download one class of images in google open images v7, but I ran into unavaible images in the process.

I want only images with vehicle license plates on it. To do so, I downloaded the bbox csv, filtered so that I can get only image ids which contains license plates. After that, I paste it in the .txt file that contains all images I want to download on the format (train/IMAGE_ID), as google recomended on https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/download_v7.html

But when I tried downloading them, I receive the error "ERROR when downloading image `train/e3b54c6b03ce4ff2`: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found", which probably happened due to the image beeing removed from the website. Is there any way to modify the google downloader.py file so that it skips unavaible images? I was unable to do so.